# webpackJsonp is not defined angular5

Tags: node.js, angular5, angular-universal

I am working on an angular5 universal app, in production server, I am getting webpackJsonp is not defined, it's working in the local environment.please give some solution.

Comment: Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: DId you see that issue? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7534 (the bit about .angular cli config; assuming you've already got the latest version)